# Saving images from webcam, always two images behind

Tags: python, pygame, webcam, raspberry-pi

I am familiar with programming but not with python or linux. I am programming in python on a raspberry pi trying to create a security camera. Here is my code to test my current problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from datetime import datetime
import pygame.camera
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

width = 640
height = 480

pic_root = "/root/cam/"

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(width,height),"RGB")

cam.start()

while True:
    raw_input("press enter")
    image = cam.get_image()
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") +'.jpg'
    filepath = pic_root+filename
    pygame.image.save(image, filepath)
```

So when I press enter, an image is taken from the webcam and saved. But the image is always two images behind. No matter how long in between saving images, the first two are always very dim as if the webcam has just started up, then the rest are always two images late.

So if I took 5 images, one with one finger up, then next with two fingers, etc, I would end up with two dark images and then the first three images. 1,2 and 3 fingers. It is as if the images are being stored somewhere then when I try to save a live images it pulls up an old one.

Am I missing something here? What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not familiar with Pygame (but I do a lot of snapshot capturing with OpenCV -- here's one of my projects: http://vmlaker.github.io/wabbit.)

I changed your code so that on every iteration, you 1) start, 2) take snapshot, and 3) stop the camera. This works a little better, in that it is only *one image behind* (instead of two.) It's still pretty weird how the old image sticks around from the previous run... I haven't figured out how to flush the camera. Notice I also changed `pic_root`, and instead of the infinite loop I'm using 3 iterations only:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

width = 640
height = 480

pic_root = './'

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(width,height),"RGB")

#cam.start()

for ii in range(3):
    raw_input("press enter")
    cam.start()
    image = cam.get_image()
    cam.stop()
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S") +'.jpg'
    filepath = pic_root+filename
    pygame.image.save(image, filepath)
```

Comment: This was how I found the code, but it caused every image to be dim and/or corrupted as if the camera was just starting up. This must be an issue with my camera which is made a bigger issue by how this library works. I'm going to look in to using a different library.

Comment: I get the same problem with opencv. Every time I capture an image it has only just turned on the webcam and everything is dark.

Comment: The "dark image" problem sounds like the camera is doing some kind of hardware initialization when it's starting up (white balance, exposure, focus, etc.) You probably will have to live with that, unless you can override defaults (try ``v4l2-ctl -l`` to see your camera settings.)

Comment: I tried several different libraries all with that initialization problem soi went back to pygame and found a work around by calling get_image() twice before actually writing it to image.

Answer (score 0):

The [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288395/saving-images-from-webcam-always-two-images-behind/70474843#comment26858606_18291099) helped, but I actually have to pull the picture three times with get_image() before saving.

I also have a wakeup function which I call after a long standby time to wake the camera. Mine has the behavior to be black after a long time.
I guess, all this weird stuff has something to do with a buffer. But the multiple call did the trick for me.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30667140)